# Strange canvas/bitmap issue

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

I have an Activity in which the user touches the eye positions on a picture, and this is supposed to draw a little white circle over each. I have a working bit of code that, using the Android FaceDetector tools, finds the eye positions and facial midpoint and draws a rectangle. The drawing part of that code, for reference, is this:

```
private void drawRectangles(){
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    
    for (int i=0; i < faceFrames.length; i++) {
        RectF r = faceFrames[i];
        if (r != null){
            canvas.drawRect(r, paint);
            Log.d(TAG, "Drew rectangle");
        }
    }
    mImageView.setImageResource(0);
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
    mImageView.draw(canvas);    
}
```

That part's fine. I figured, as a method that is called from onTouchEvent, that I could use the following to draw a circle:

```
private void makeDrawableLayer(int x, int y, int touchCount){
     if (touchCount == 1){
        Bitmap eyeOneBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(mBitmap);
        Canvas c1 = new Canvas(eyeOneBmp);
        c1.drawCircle(x, y, 5, eyePaint);
        
        mImageView.setImageResource(0);
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(eyeOneBmp);
        mImageView.draw(c1);
        
     }
}
```

Here are screen shots showing the result of each code snippet. The first picture is the rectangle drawn on the face. The second picture shows the very strange result I get when I attempt to draw using the second code snippet. Note, however, that I had specified x and y as 10, 10 for the circle's position when drawing the second output. It's the same thing when I give it the passed-in eye position coordinates, just with the pixelated circle coming from wherever the eye is.

Does anyone have any idea what the heck is going on with this behavior?

Thanks so much.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why are you calling mImageView.draw(c1)? That will draw the ImageView to the bitmap.

Comment: @alanv -- I drew the ImageView to the bitmap only because I had done that in the rectangle drawing method. If I remove that line of code, nothing happens at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found that you can basically only draw one time to the canvas before needing to make a class that extends View to start calling methods from. What I ended up needing to do was: customView.prepareCircle(), customView.invalidate(), and then parentView.addView(customView). And actually, I could only prepare, invalidate, and re-add the modified custom view to the canvas once before having to make any subsequent calls from a Runnable on the UI thread. I am not under the impression this is an ideal way to do it (certainly doesn't *feel* elegant), but it is giving me the results I want:

[image]